# A sleep primitive for CUDA device-side code

Tags: c++, timer, cuda

I've so far been spared the need to waste any cycles on the GPU, but it seems like this might change. After getting some information I was missing about the semantics of CUDA's `clock64()` function, I've written the following bit of code for use in kernels (or other device-side functions):

```
// Shouldn't this be typedef'ed in the CUDA headers somewhere?
using clock_value_t = long long;

namespace detail {

__device__ void sleep(
    clock_value_t            num_cycles, 
    volatile clock_value_t*  buffer_to_avoid_optimization)
{
    clock_value_t start = clock64();
    clock_value_t now;
    while (true) {
        now = clock64();
        // (Note the assumption of no wrap-around)
        clock_value_t cycles_elapsed = now - start;
        if (cycles_elapsed >= num_cycles) { break; }
    }
    // The memory write here should (hopefully) prevents the compiler
    // from optimizing the entire loop away
    *buffer_to_avoid_optimization = now - start;
}

} // namespace detail

/**
 * Have the executing warp busy-sleep until at least a certain
 * number of SM clock cycles have passed.
 *
 * @note The exact number of cycles busy-slept will depend on how soon the
 * warp will be scheduled to execute again after the last time it
 * iterates the elapsed-cycles check.
 *
 * @param num_cycles The minimum number of cycles to busy-sleep
 */
__device__ void sleep(clock_value_t num_cycles)
{
    static volatile clock_value_t buffer;
    detail::sleep(num_cycles, &buffer);
}
```

Other than general observations which are welcome, I have a few questions:

- Is this approach reasonable, or should I be doing something very different?
- Is there a better way of avoiding the `while(true)` loop from being optimized away?
- Do I even need the `volatile` modifier on `buffer_to_avoid_optimization`?
- Could I use a reference instead of a pointer?
- Should I give it a different name?

Comment: I have good luck with `long long start = clock64(); while(clock64()< (start+DELAY_CLOCKS));` In my experience it never gets optimized away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as Robert Crovella suggests, the `clock64()` calls don't get optimized away, then this should be enough:

```
using clock_value_t = long long;

__device__ void sleep(clock_value_t sleep_cycles)
{
    clock_value_t start = clock64();
    clock_value_t cycles_elapsed;
    do { cycles_elapsed = clock64() - start; } 
    while (cycles_elapsed < sleep_cycles);
}
```